# python zipline: How to import data bundle with minutes data

Tags: python, zipline

How to import data bundles with 1 minute data(forex 1 minute) into zipline, I did similar procedure with EOD stock data successfully. However, it can't be imported with minute data, there are no error message but the folder is empty (forex-bundle/2020-09-18T09;26;46.177573). Please feel free to comment.

**~/.zipline/extension.py**

```
import pandas as pd

from zipline.data.bundles import register
from zipline.data.bundles.csvdir import csvdir_equities

    start_session = pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00', tz='utc')
    end_session = pd.Timestamp('2020-09-11 16:58:00', tz='utc')
    
    register(
        'forex-bundle',
        csvdir_equities(
            ['M1'],
            '/data/forex/USDJPY',
        ),
        calendar_name='24/7',
        minutes_per_day=1440,
        start_session=start_session,
        end_session=end_session
    )
```

**CSV data in Minutes** (/data/forex/USDJPY/M1/USDJPY.csv)

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume,dividend,split
2020-06-01 00:00:00,107.634,107.637,107.628,107.635,0.0,0.0,1.0
2020-06-01 00:01:00,107.635,107.648,107.634,107.648,0.0,0.0,1.0
..........
..........
2020-09-11 16:57:00,106.147,106.156,106.146,106.146,0.0,0.0,1.0
2020-09-11 16:58:00,106.144,106.169,106.144,106.156,0.0,0.0,1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed **'M1'** to **'minute'**; the directory **'minute'** has been hardcoded in the source code, it can't accept other than **'daily'** or **'minute'**